# Secure Copy of Directories and / or Files To a Linux Server

Tags: linux, scp

When copying files or directories to a Linux server, what is the difference between 'scp -r' and 'scp -R'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `-r` is the recursive flag and `-R` is an invalid flag. Use `man` pages for these kinds of questions, `man scp`